# Activate Conda environment inside R script

Tags: python, r, conda

I am new to R coding.

I want to run an R script called from a Python script.

The Python script will use a Conda environment, env1, while the R script will use a different Conda environment, env2, in Linux.

So, I activate env1 before running the python script: `conda activate /condaenv/env1/`

Then I run the python script `python testpy.py` (this python script will call the R script `testr.R`).

My python script (testpy.py) is as follow:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['Rscript','testr.R','hello'])
```

My Rscript `testr.R` will be as follows:

```
#!/condaenv/env2/bin/Rscript
library(Peaks)
library(httr)
```

I want to import all the R library inside the `testr.R` script from /condaenv/env2.

But I don't know ***how can an R script activate a Conda environment (env2) and will the R script run using the package installed in env2?***

Comment: Could you provide some more details about your setup? Like how is R invoked from Python script (subproces, rpy2, ...)?  Have you tested [conda run](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/run.html) to execute R script in specific conda env or would your setup work with [nested conda activations](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#nested-activation)?

Comment: @margusl, Thank you for reply. I already modify my question by adding the setup. I haven't tested both conda run and nested conda activations. May I know where can `conda run` be used? I mean is `conda run` need to be command inside the `testpy.py` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note regarding the title ("*Activate Conda environment inside R script*"), just as you activate python env before executing your the python script, R environment should be activated before invoking the R script.

Setting up 2 conda enviruonments and using [`conda run`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/run.html) for executing Python script and invoking R from Python:

###### Conda envs

```bash
# base python env:
conda create -n conda_python -c conda-forge python
# base r env + httr:
conda create -n conda_r -c conda-forge r-base r-httr
```

###### Test scripts

```py
# testpy.py

import os
import subprocess
print('CONDA_PREFIX (py) :', os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'])
# subprocess.call('conda run -n conda_r Rscript testr.R', shell=True)
# or
subprocess.call(['conda', 'run',  '-n', 'conda_r', 'Rscript', 'testr.R'] )
```

```r
# testr.R

message("-- R --")
message("CONDA_PREFIX (R)  : ", Sys.getenv("CONDA_PREFIX"))
message("R .libPaths()     : ", .libPaths())
resp <- httr::GET("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/info?site=stackoverflow")
message('Questions in SO : ', httr::content(resp, as ="parsed")$items[[1]]$total_questions)
```

###### Executing `testpy.py`

(when `conda_python` is not currently activated environment)

```bash
# conda run -n conda_python python testpy.py
CONDA_PREFIX (py) : /home/marguslt/miniconda3/envs/conda_python
-- R --
CONDA_PREFIX (R)  : /home/marguslt/miniconda3/envs/conda_r
R .libPaths()     : /home/marguslt/miniconda3/envs/conda_r/lib/R/library
Questions in SO : 23249251
```

##### As an alternative, using conda [nested activation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#nested-activation) :

py script replaced with:

```py
# testpy_noconda.py

import os
import subprocess
print('CONDA_PREFIX (py) :', os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'])
subprocess.call(['Rscript', 'testr.R'] )
```

Activating both environments with `--stack` option and running `testpy_noconda.py`:

```bash
(base): conda activate conda_python
(conda_python): conda activate --stack conda_r
(conda_r): python testpy_noconda.py
CONDA_PREFIX (py) : /home/marguslt/miniconda3/envs/conda_r
-- R --
CONDA_PREFIX (R)  : /home/marguslt/miniconda3/envs/conda_r
R .libPaths()     : /home/marguslt/miniconda3/envs/conda_r/lib/R/library
Questions in SO : 23249325
```

Environment:

```bash
(conda_r): env | grep CONDA_
CONDA_EXE=/home/marguslt/miniconda3/bin/conda
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/marguslt/miniconda3/bin/python
CONDA_SHLVL=3
CONDA_PREFIX=/home/marguslt/miniconda3/envs/conda_r
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=conda_r
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(conda_r)
CONDA_PREFIX_1=/home/marguslt/miniconda3
CONDA_PREFIX_2=/home/marguslt/miniconda3/envs/conda_python
CONDA_STACKED_3=true
```

Comment: I tried using conda run method. But I got the below error.
```(/condaenv/conda_python) bash-4.2$ python testpy.py
CONDA_PREFIX (py) : /condaenv/conda_python
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(32): Subprocess for 'conda run [u'Rscript', u'testr.R', u'F10N']' command failed.  (See above for error)
-- R --
CONDA_PREFIX (R) : /conda_env/conda_r
R.libPaths()     : /usr/lib64/R/library/conda_env/conda_r/lib/R/library
Error: invalid multibyte character in parser at line 1
Execution halted```

Comment: Inside subprocess of the testpy.py, I wrote like this 
```subprocess.call(['conda', 'run',  '-p', '/conda_env/conda_r', 'Rscript', 'testr.R'] )```
***May I know why this subprocess command failed in python script?*** Moreover when I print the .libPaths(), it gives ```/usr/lib64/R/library/conda_env/conda_r/lib/R/library```. It is strange, why /conda_env/conda_r/lib/R/library path is concatenated with /usr/lib64/R/library? "/usr/lib64/R/library" is one directory and "/conda_env/conda_r/lib/R/library" is one directory.

Comment: Lastly, why I got ***Error: invalid multibyte character in parser at line 1 Execution halted***?  My testr.R script is ```#!/conda_env/conda_r/bin/Rscript
message("-- R --")
message("CONDA_PREFIX (R) : ", Sys.getenv("CONDA_PREFIX"))
message("R.libPaths()     : ", .libPaths())
library(futile.logger)
library(tryCatchLog)
library(warbleR)
library(httr)```

Comment: may I know when I used conda nested activation, python script will use which env? Is it conda_python or conda_r? My python script need to use the package from the conda_python environment.

Comment: Nested is most likely less robust and and depends more on your setup and content of your envs. R script gets called and is executed, so your subprocess call in py should be fine,  though I'd start with minimal changes, perhaps it's the loaded library or your editor setup.  But that whole system setup is likely not reproducible by others. Is this a multi-user environment administered by someone else, hpc cluster of your uni? There's also a global R (and/or conda ) installation? Organisations should have documented guidelines and support available, solving it correctly can be quite site-specific